# Storing list output as a pandas dataframe column while doing regex data cleaning

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a column data and then my job is to store the cleaned information in the same column intact so that it then can be fed into tf-idf vectoriser. The following code that I have written works well but stores the output in a list. I want the clean output to be stored in the same column and not in the list. My goal is to keep my information intact and in the correct format.

```
#Cleaning comment section
import re
import nltk

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

def text_cleaner(text,num):
   newString = text.lower()
   newString = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', newString)
   newString = re.sub(r"[0-9]", "", newString)
   newString = re.sub(',','.', newString)
   newString = re.sub(r"'s\b","",newString)
   newString = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", newString) 
   newString = re.sub(r"Ä¢", "", newString)
   newString = re.sub(r"¬∑", "", newString)
   newString = re.sub(r"\'", "", newString)    
   newString = re.sub(r"\"", "", newString)   
   newString = re.sub(r"\n", "", newString)    
   newString = re.sub(r"\r", "", newString) 
if(num==0):
    tokens = [w for w in newString.split() if not w in stopwords]
else:
    tokens=newString.split()
long_words=[]
for i in tokens:
    if len(i)>1:  #removing short word
        long_words.append(i)   
return (" ".join(long_words)).strip()
#call the function
X = []
for t in df1['CHARACTERISTICS']:
   X.append(text_cleaner(t,0))
```

Either the list `X` should be converted back to the dataframe column C1 or the cleaning function should return the clean string directly in column C1. I tried the following code to do that but resulted in an error:

```
df['C1'] = df['C1'].apply(text_cleaner(t,0))
```

Comment: What is the functionality of ```newString = re.sub(r"'s\b","",newString)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answers my question

```
df['C1'] = pd.DataFrame(X)
```